# I have same image with 2 different urls but only one works

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to view in my app youtube thumbnails. I search for element with Opera and Chrome. When I use `url` from `src` tag with Opera, it works. But when I try to do the same thing with Chrome it doesn't show the image.

URLs:

- [Opera](http://%20%20%20https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GqKJY5Cm_qs/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEiCKgBEF5IWvKriqkDFQgBFQAAAAAYASUAAMhCPQCAokN4AQ==&rs=AOn4CLBtm0NiWn48uURr3j4lZ9HLhA0rwQ)
- [Chrome](http://%20%20%20https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GqKJY5Cm_qs/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEbCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDDggBFQAAiEIYAXABwAEG&rs=AOn4CLAhop_cweaOOHgDNcplAvaaxjenNA)
- [Playlist](http://%20%20%20https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyBm7dB8ou_1w2yAtVGcfSyvFBwR7KgtO)

**Form1.cs**

```cs
video[] videos = new video[5];
for(ushort i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    videos[i] = new video();
    videos[i].Url = "Link from Chrome";
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(videos[i]);
}
```

**video.cs**

```
#region Properties
private string _url;

[Category("Custom Props")]
public string Url {
      get { return _url; }
      set { _url = value;
            Thumbnail.ImageLocation = value;
      }
}
#endregion
```

Difference between links from browsers: https://youtu.be/nqmo4aZtunk

Comment: I don't fully understand your question / problem. your app is a winforms app? If so, how would you be 'using opera' or 'using chrome'. Those 2 img srcs are different, but both are valid. Just use the one that works for you?

Comment: yes it's winforms app. It's supposed to get the url of any video's thumbnail in the playlist by itself and I want it to work from almost any browser using selenium.

Comment: 'It's supposed to get the url of any video's thumbnail in the playlist by itself'. Does this part work? If not, what is it doing versus what are you expecting. This should have nothing to do with opera / chrome, correct?

Comment: I will add short video in few minutes.

Comment: 'and I want it to work from almost any browser using selenium' - ah, ok, i think maybe you're using selenium to make your queries against youtube. You may want to look at using the YouTube API directly, or make web requests from within your app and use the HTML Agility pack or similar to parse the results

Comment: @czromXL all content related to the question must be present as text in the question itself. Adding video is not considered "improvement" from SO point of view.

Comment: Check if that's just session that force old link from same account to expire, and therefore only "new" window works.